# MySQL Change Password command run in MySQL on Ubuntu Server results in strange Character Changes in terminal

Tags: mysql, bash, ubuntu, hash, virtualbox

I'm running an Ubuntu Server with MySQL in VirtualBox and trying to change the password for a user.

I run:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

to access MySQL. At this point, and with any other commands not trying to see a user's password, everything is working.

In MySQL ( ) I run:

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.user;
```

After I run this, the entire display and terminal change. The output and command line are both displaying strange characters. I run this command which works just fine. What gives?

```
SELECT user FROM mysql.user;
```

Here are the before and after screen shots:

[Screen Shot Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zUII.png),
[Screen Shot After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lD4v7.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have no clue why this is happening. Is this an Ubuntu thing, a MySQL thing or a VirtualBox thing? I'm a noob so this is just an uninformed theory but could it have something to do with MySQL `authenticated_string` and something to do with hashing?

It actually creates a change that persists even upon typing `exit` and hitting `Enter`, exiting MySQL and back to the Ubuntu command line where the weird characters are still showing.

EDIT:

I was following a blog tutorial and inserted `<db-password>` as the password when creating the MySQL user. I was supposed to insert an actual new password instead but figured I'd just use that. Are the `<`, `-` or `>` characters that I used when setting the user's MySQL password maybe causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this was a character encoding issue in MySQL because `SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'root';` doesn't have the same issue. Because of that, I believe the issue only occurs at that one user's password data point where the `<`, `-` and `>` characters were used. Maybe someone else can provide a better answer explaining more thoroughly why this occurs. Specifically, I'm curious as to how this issue in MySQL is then able to affect the appearance of the Ubuntu Command Line once the MySQL shell is exited.